# Asynchronous props in vue

Tags: asynchronous, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a method that makes an asynchronous call.

```
methods: {

        getPercentCovered() {
          this.getPercentageCompletedBySubject(1).then((percent) => {
          return percent;
        });
},
```

It calculates a percent from an value returned by an ajax request.

The issue I suppose is the delay

```
<progress-bar :percent="getPercentCovered()"></progress-bar>
```

The value is never passed in before the prop is rendered. Is there a work around?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is not the delay. The problem is that `getPercentCovered()` doesn't ever return `percent`: it actually returns `undefined`. You cannot `return` the result of an asynchronous operation: the most you could do in such a scenario is return the whole promise and handle it in the child.

[This famous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) highlights the general problem of your code.

Now, regarding the Vue part of your question, there are several ways to handle this. I guess the most straightforward is to pass a prop to the child which gets updated when the `getPercentageCompletedBySubject` resolves. I'm putting the call in the `created()` lifecycle hook. Maybe you should move it to an event handler, that really depends on the real use case:

```
//script
data() {
  return {
    percent: '', //or maybe null or whatever empty value.
  };
},
methods: {
        getPercentCovered() {
          this.getPercentageCompletedBySubject(1).then((percent) => {
          this.percent = percent; //instead of return from a handler, which does nothing ,
          // now we assign to this.percent
        });
},
created(){
  this.getPercentCovered();
}

//template
<progress-bar :percent="percent"></progress-bar>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got it working but feel there is a cleaner way. I can probably do the calculation before this component is required and save it in a vuex store.